# Netty using database connection and query?

Tags: java, mysql, netty

I'm newbie on Netty and networking and would like to get some examples on how to connect to MySql using asynchronous connection. Could you bring some examples of source code please? 
Thanks beforehand!

P.S.
I've googled but couldn't find any example!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an async mysql/postgresql driver written on top of netty:
https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-async

Comment: It's written in Scala! How can I use that? Do you have any code snippet?